# Pidyon Peter chamor on c section born donkeys

Tags: halacha, animals, pregnancy-birth, contemporary-halacha, peter-chamor

Does the mitzvah of Pidyon Peter Chamor (redeeming the firstborn donkey), apply if the donkey was born through C section (caesarean section)? Or does the Halakha not consider that is birth for the purpose of the mitzvah? What is the Halacha here?

Comment: Is the Halacha different by donkeys vs. human Bechorim?

Comment: Rambam afaict only mentions this rule by human and kosher-animal firstborn. It's hard to imagine why it wouldn't apply here too

Answer (score 5, accepted):

While we have משניות that teach us that a יוצא דפן is excluded from בכור בהמה טהורה (see [בכורות ב:ט](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Mishnah_Bekhorot.2.9)) and בכור אדם (see [בכורות ח:ב](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Mishnah_Bekhorot.8.2)), this halacha is not mentioned explicitly when the mishna deals with פטר חמור in the first perek, so there is room to ask why not.

That being said, the דרשה in שמות יג on the wording **פֶּטֶר כׇּל רֶחֶם** and **פֶּטֶר רֶחֶם** to exclude יוצא דפן (see [מכילתא דרשב"י](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Mekhilta_DeRabbi_Shimon_Ben_Yochai.13.1) and [גמ' בכורות יט עמ' א](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Bekhorot.19a)) in conjunction with the wording **פטר** for חמור coming on the heels of the language פטר רחם, would cause one to think that the דרשה is a general one applying to all three types of bechor: בכור אדם, בהמה טהורה, פטר חמור (*also see the usage of these phrases in שמות לד:יט,כ*)

Still, the only places I have noticed so far that specifically mention **the exclusion of יוצא דפן also applying to פטר חמור** are:

**1** - in the [**מנחת חינוך - מצוה כב**](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Minchat_Chinukh.22.1.7):

> ולענין **יוצא דופן** ושאר ענינים **הכל שוה לבכור בהמה טהורה** עיין ר"מ וטוש"ע

Notice that he implies that the Rambam (see [הלכות בכורות פרק ב](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Mishneh_Torah%2C_Firstlings.2.4)) and the Shulchan Aruch (see [יורה דעה שטו:ב](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Shulchan_Arukh%2C_Yoreh_De%27ah.315.2)) hold that such is the case even though I haven't seen either specifically mention the law for פטר חמור (*eg. missing from יורה דעה שכא*).

**2** - in the [**סמ"ק ס' רמד**](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Sefer_Mitzvot_Katan.244.2)

> וכן הבא אחר נפלים **ואחר יוצא דופן**: בין באדם בין **בבהמה טמאה** בין בטהורה